# get data from two table(query)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i'm getting an error when querying two table . "Incorrect syntax near 'tbl_programme'." when i run the below codes.I want to retrieve data from two tables.

```
// Define the ADO.NET objects.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_team";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dsPubs = new DataSet();

        // Try to open database and read information.
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dsPubs, "tbl_team");

            // This command is still linked to the data adapter.
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * tbl_programme";
            adapter.Fill(dsPubs, "tbl_student_project_choice");

            DataRelation test = new DataRelation("test",
            dsPubs.Tables["tbl_team"].Columns["teamId"],
            dsPubs.Tables["tbl_student_project_choice"].Columns["choiceGroupId"]);
            dsPubs.Relations.Add(test);


        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have missed `FROM` keyword in your `SELECT` statement,

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_programme";
                         // ^ HERE
```